# Magit shows magit-diff with HEAD^ instead of HEAD when invoked from console

Tags: magit

When I start a commit from console (zsh on mac os Terminal) using `git commit -a`, then Emacs opens two windows as emacsclient in my existing Emacs App Window. One is the correct COMMIT_EDITMSG. The other is a magit-diff window. However, magit uses HEAD^ instead of HEAD as revision. The title says "Changes from HEAD^ to working tree" and that is what is shown.

In contrast, when I run magit-commit from within Emacs, the correct magit-diff window is opened, showing HEAD agains my working tree.

Any idea why this is and how I can fix it?

Emacs from brew: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1911)) of 2017-04-21
Magit 20180410.1528, Git 2.17.0, Emacs 25.2.1, darwin

Answer (score 2):

Both diffs can be useful and you can toggle between them by pressing <kbd>C-c C-d</kbd>.

Initially the diff is shown using the function `magit-commit-diff`, which decides which of these diffs to show based on the value of `last-command`, or if that isn't one of the commands it knows how to handle it falls back to this:

```
(if (magit-anything-staged-p)
    (magit-diff-staged nil args)
  (magit-diff-while-amending args))
```

Since you didn't invoke the commit using a Magit command, `magit-commit-diff` does not know which diff would be most appropriate and falls back to the above heuristic.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, using `C-c C-d` after using `git commit -a` will toggle to Staged Changes (which may be empty) and the `HEAD^` vs. working tree diff. It doesn't toggle to `HEAD` vs. working tree for me.